# Left->Right, Down, Right->Left, Down, Left->Right layout in Graphviz

Tags: graphviz, flowchart

I have a very long linear (not many branches) flowchart that shows up in graphviz as either too tall to fit on a single page, or too wide (if direction was left to right)

Is there an easy way to have graphviz lay out the graph in such a way that it goes Left to right, then down, then right to left, then down? (I hope this explains it well).

[image: Desired layout]

Something like this (drawn in visio)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually quite easy to get exactly what you want:

```
digraph so 
{
    node[ shape = square ];
    { rank = same; 1 2 3 }
    { rank = same; 6 5 4 }
    { rank = same; 7 8 }

    1 -> 2 -> 3;
    3 -> 4;
    6 -> 5 -> 4 [ dir = back ];
    6 -> 7;
    7 -> 8;
}
```

yields

[image]

`rank = same` makes sure that the boxes defined here stay side by side; without that they would be aligned vertically.

Since the boxes are drawn left to right in the order they are defined, it's necessary to define them the way done above for the 2nd row.

That's also the reason for having the arrows in the middle row pointing backward - in reality the edge goes from `6` to `5` and from `5` to `4`.

From here you can start fine tuning - labels in the boxes instead of the numbers, longer edges, colors...

Comment: I was hoping for something easier and less hack-ish than this (for example, dir="LRDRLD" or something like that :P but this works I guess